# Handling realtime in laravel

Tags: laravel, websocket, real-time

*I know this will be closed question but I can't find what I want so I need to ask pros over here.*

What is the best option for real time content in laravel app like messages, notifications and even loading new post as example.

**Besides using pusher or other services.**

Something like nodejs and socketio **but 
what are the best
 options for laravel apps**?

Comment: https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to take advantage of Laravel's Broadcasting functionality then going with a [supported driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites) is likely best to get you started.

Which means that if you don't want to use Pusher then it is a combination of Redis and Socket.io.

Our small team doesn't have a dedicated dev-ops team, so we went with Pusher and have had a good experience with minimal server config. We do also use Redis for pubsub communication between a couple of microservices, some api throttling management, and of course queues. It might be worth noting that if you are a [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) user it provisions Redis out of the box for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think of your software needs.

Pusher comes with a Free Tier, and its easier to implement than Socket.io

Setting up Socket.io will come with some learning curve, you may want to expend your time on other functionality of your project. But hey its free right? unless you consider time more valuable, which is almost always the case when it comes to programming.

With Pusher, you can quickly start your project, focus on other less trivial requirements. 
Socket.io may save you money, but only once is running.

If your project doesn't consume the free tier completely, it's a no brainer.